# Python: reverse guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I wrote this code for a reverse guessing game but it prints c twice for the first time. Keep in mind (d=correct) (b=bigger) (k=smaller).

```py
import random
c = random.randint(1,99)
print(c)
a = str(input())
while a != "d":
    if a == "b":
        print(c)
        c = random.randint(c,99)
        a = str(input())
    elif a == "k":        
        print(c)
        c = random.randint(1,c)
        a = str(input())
    elif a == "d":
     break
```

The output is like this:

```
67
b
67
```

I want 67 to be printed once.

I tried removing `print(c)` in lines 3, 7, 11.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You print, then check for input, then print out the same value again... Did you want to print the new c value, after the random function?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes

Comment: Then move the print statement before the input call? Just like you did after the import

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks! sorry It was a really stupid mistake I started learning recently

Comment: Keep in mind, 67 could eventually print again with a combination of b and k inputs since you'd get randint(67, 99), so say 70, then randint(1, 70) could be 67... If you want to actually print without duplicates, you need to track previous values

Comment: @OneCricketeer How do I track previous values?

Comment: Store them in a list. Check if the list contains the new random value. If so, compute another random value until that's not true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to print c two times, simply try adding the print statement after generating the new random number as you did the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import random
c=random.randint(1,99)
print(c)
a=str(input())
while a!="d":
    if a=="b":
        c=random.randint(c,99)
        print(c)
        a=str(input())
    elif a=="k":
        c=random.randint(1,c)
        print(c)
        a=str(input())
    elif a=="d":
     break
```